# How to embed variable in xpath

Tags: python-3.x, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to embed a variable into an xpath expression. This is very straight-forward, but for some reason, it is not working for me.

The following code below works great but I want to make the string `Feb` a variable so I can pass through Jan, Mar, etc.

```
reverse_month_select = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='datepicker-months']/table/tbody/tr/td/span[contains(@class, 'month') and text() = 'Feb']")[0]
```

For some reason, this code fails as I receive an IndexError:

> list index out of range month_select = "Jan"
>
> reverse_month_select =
>   browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='datepicker-months']/table/tbody/tr/td/span[contains(@class,
>   'month') and text() = " + month_select + "]")[0]

Comment: How exactly did you try to pass the variables?

Comment: Exactly as the above code. So declaring a variable month_select as a string and then passing that through the x-path expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still now sure what exactly went wrong, but try feeding the months to the xpath expression using f-strings and let me know if it works:

```
cal = ['Jan','Feb','March']  #etc.

for month in cal:
    expression = f"//div[@class='datepicker-months']/table/tbody/tr/td/span[contains(@class, 'month') and text() = '{month}']"
```

And then change your definition to:

```
reverse_month_select = browser.find_elements_by_xpath(expression)[0]
```

Comment: Absolutely brilliant. Thanks alot!